# Design support library - Which version to use with SDK v21

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-support-design

I have problems to understand the version scheme of the support libraries and when to use which version. Currently I have a project with `compileSdkVersion 21`, `minSdkVersion 21` and `targetSdkVersion 21` and want to use the android design support library. 
When I use `com.android.support:design:22.2.0` the project compiles but I get a Gradle warning:

```
"This support library should not use a different version (22) than the `compileSdkVersion` (21)".
```

When I use `com.android.support:design:23.0.1` I get some compilation errors like:

```
"Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
```

I thought I can use always the highest version of the support libraries as long as the `compileSdkVersion` is lower or equal, but that seems wrong.

Can I use the design support library when compiling against API level 21?

Comment: You can only use versions up to and including your `compileSdkVersion`, so 21 in your case.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Support Library should always match the `compileSdkVersion` even if the `targetSdkVersion` or `minSdkVersion` are lower. If you want to use the design library you will need to set `compileSdkVersion` to at least 22 and library version 22.2.0.

The reason for that is simple. The version of the library reflects the version of the Android sdk against it was built. If you try to use a higher level version of the support library than the `compileSdkVersion` it may not find resources that were added in a later version.

Answer (score 19):

You can use one of these:

```
//You have to use compileSdkVersion=22
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'

//You have to use compileSdkVersion=23
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
```

The design library has dependency with appcompat-v7 library.
You **can't use the v23.0.x version compiling with api 22** (it is the reason of `"Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'`.

Also, because the first version of the design library is 22, **you can't use** compileSdk=21.

Comment: where can I see all versions for particular support library?

Comment: @BharatDodeja Here the full list:http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html