# Cannot resolve symbol 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse

Tags: android

I have been created project in android studio,but the following error were occured.

**Error:**

```
C:\Learning\Android\Design\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml

Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 

org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\Android\build-tools\22.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/src/googleplex-android/mnc-supportlib-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v23/styles_base_text.xml -->
<eat-comment/>
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse"/>
<!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/src/googleplex-android/mnc-supportlib-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v23/themes_base.xml -->
<eat-comment/>
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat"/>
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
<style name="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- We can use the platform drawable on v23+ -->
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
    <!-- We can use the platform styles on v23+ -->
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">?android:attr/actionMenuTextColor</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">?android:attr/actionMenuTextAppearance</item>

    <item name="controlBackground">@drawable/abc_control_background_material</item>
</style>
<style name="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- We can use the platform drawable on v23+ -->
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
    <!-- We can use the platform styles on v23+ -->
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">?android:attr/actionMenuTextColor</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">?android:attr/actionMenuTextAppearance</item>

    <item name="controlBackground">@drawable/abc_control_background_material</item>
</style>
<!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/src/googleplex-android/mnc-supportlib-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v23/styles_base.xml -->
<eat-comment/>
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored"/>
```

Comment: Whether you are using, studio or eclipse?

Comment: did you use `compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Design support library - Which version to use with SDK v21](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939463/design-support-library-which-version-to-use-with-sdk-v21)

Comment: I'm using android studio @Nigam Patro
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.0'

Comment: @prabhakaran make your compileSdkVersion to 23 and check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set your compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion to match the major version of the support library you are using:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.your.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode YOUR CODE
        versionName "Your.Version.Number"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
}
```