# This support library should not use a different version than the compileSdkVersion

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am the beginner in android and started using Android Studio. When i try to add CARDVIEW to my application , i am getting this error.And my ANDROID STUDIO is fully uptodate and i have downloaded and support libraries required.Please help to fix this and Thanks in advance

[image: Below is my error screenshot]

Comment: Have look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939463/design-support-library-which-version-to-use-with-sdk-v21)

Comment: all version in dependencies have same just change com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.2 to com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.2` to
`com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0`.

It is happening because you compile your project with 22 sdk version, but gradle is trying to download card view for older version.